# Как наиболее правильно реализовать проверку формы для поля в БД, в котором не может быть отрицательного числа

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста наилучший алгоритм для проверки поля формы. Понимаю что наилучший вариант json но с ним полный затык ).

Есть форма с динамическими полями. Поля создаются из JS (Добавить строку) и заполняются из модального окна. Количество строк  не ограничено.

```
 <form>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><input name="name[]"/></td>
     <td><input name ="quantiy[]"/></td>
     <td><button>Добавить строку</button></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

По submit - контроллер с записью в БД, при этом поле quantity  c decrement
Валидацию хочется на лету поля quantity, чтобы при decrement не было отрицательного числа. Пробовал несколько JS - не хочется их сюда выкладывать )). Подтолкните пожалуйста к решению.

Comment: поставьте в колонке таблицы свойство UNSIGNED. Тогда отрицательный значения туда не запишутся.

Comment: Это хорошо. Но нужно оповестить пользователя!!

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать `input type="number"` с атрибутом `min="0"` тогда js не понадобится

[ссылка на документацию по input type="number"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp)

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="name[]" /></td>
      <td><input min="0" type="number" name="quantiy[]" /></td>
      <td><button>Добавить строку</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Нет. Не підходить. Я наверное не совсем точно описано проблему.  Так например в базе есть   name č quantity =0. Если обновить это поле с помощью decrement даже на 1, то в этом поле станет -1. А это не допустимо. Нужно как то сравнить эти существующее и вводимые поле и если вводимые больше предупредить пользователя м не обновлять базу.

Comment: @VakulinOleg используйте мутаторы